# Calling function defined using useCallback after setting the state on which it depends

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I defined a function using useCallback, depending on a state. I want to call this function from another, which change the state before calling it and defined using useCallback as well. How can I do?

Example:

```
const refreshPage = useCallback(
    () => {
        if (state == '1')
            // action
    },
    [state]
);

const onChangeText = useCallback(
    (state) => {
        setState(state);
        refreshPage();
    },
    [refreshPage]
);
```

Here, when onChangeText will be called, it will update the state and the definition of `refreshPage`, but it will not call `refreshPage` with the new state I defined.

I precise that it's only an example and and I use useEffect to load data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do some action when `state` changed and `state` equal to one, you better handle it in `useEffect` rather than `useCallback` and you do not need to call anything like `refreshPage` at all

```
const refreshPage = useCallback(() => {
   // load data here
},[]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (state == '1'){
    refreshPage()
  }
},[state]);

const onChangeText = useCallback((state) => {
     setState(state);
 },[]);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I think it will work but I used the useEffect function to load data, and I need it to be called one time: only on page load. How I can support both? Maybe by adding a state to check if the page already loaded?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, you might need to update your question and provide more details such as your `useEffect` to load data...

I saw you comment in the other answer that you will use `refreshPage ` in many places. Please check my updated answer to get that.

Comment: I discovered that we can use several useEffect functions inside a class, so I can use one for loading the page and one depending on my states.

Comment: You can not use `useEffect` in class component, hooks can only be used in a functional component or a custom hooks. Yes in functional component you can use many `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it won't be called with the updated state is that `useCallback` will update the value of the function when the component rerenders and when you call `setState(state)` and `refreshPage()`, the component haven't rerendered and it's still using the `refreshPage` that haven't updated yet.

One way to make this work is to pass the state to `refreshPage` and use it there, instead of relaying on the `state` that will be changed on the `useCallback`.

```
const refreshPage = useCallback(
    // added state here 
    (state) => {
        if (state == '1')
            // action
    },
    [] // removed state  from here
);

const onChangeText = useCallback(
    (state) => {
        setState(state);
        refreshPage(state);
    },
    [refreshPage]
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I simplified in the example. I am using the ```refreshPage``` function in many places, and not only depending on one state. I don't want this function to handle the setStates function.